# Настройка .htaccess (отображение файла из подкаталога, при этом в url не должен указываться каталог файла)

Tags: .htaccess, apache

Имеется папка test.local и в ней находятся несколько каталогов и файлов:
- app/
- public/
- .htaccess
и т.д

Непосредственно вопрос, как реализовать следующий функционал: при переходе по следующему url: http://test.local отобразить индексный файл, который находится тут public/index.php, но при этом в url **не** должен отображаться путь к каталогу с файлом, примерно такой http://test.local/public

Пробован несколько вариантов, но не получалось убрать в url путь к каталогу

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решить получилось не через .htaccess, а непосредственно через gui OpenServer.
В трее кликаем правой кнопкой мыши по иконке OpenSever -> Настройка -> Домены.
В выпадающем списке Управление доменами ставим "Ручное+Автопоиск". В имя домена вписываем названием папки проекта (который лежит в папке OSPanel/domains/) и путь указываем непосредственно до папки public проекта.